# Abnormal Visibility Issue on GooglePlay

Tags: google-play

I'm a developer with a 10-year history. My problem is not a common problem. I published a game 10 days ago. My game was downloaded 15 thousand times (My rating 4.6) in a week.  My game is in the racing category. But my game can't enter new or trending games in any country's racing category.

I'm comparing my game to other games published on a similar date. Many games have not reached the 1000 download but are available on the list. It's looks like an embargo on my game.

I've had a similar situation in my game before. The game has received 240,000 downloads (rating 4.7) in the first 23 days  but has not entered any list. Google keeps apps on new and trends list for 30 days. I was able to stay for 7 days because of the problem. After this game I have released 4 more games I have not experienced this problem. The last game I released a week ago. I'm having the same problem in this game.

Maybe you can say no more new games list on Google Play. You can see a list of new games when you look at the computer. When you published new app or game.   If your app is not in list of new games(on computer) category. this means, You are not listing anywhere on mobile. This list reflections of mobile's lists.

You can follow these listings by country from appannie.com

My question is someone who is experiencing this problem ?
Or another question, Do you think, What is the cause of this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Google puts a lot of work into fighting spam installs - you can read about some of it on [this blog post](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/10/keeping-the-play-store-trusted-fighting-fraud-and-spam-installs.html). If you are getting a lot of these installs by paying a company to provide you with installs, or through some other mechanism that seems suspicious to Google then you might not get into the new or trending category.

Comment: My all downloads are natural. We are only using adwords and facebook for advertisements.